# Convert European date to Date in R?

Tags: r, date

I would like to convert European format date (DDMMYYY), tpoo extract in into separate years and months: e.g. using `lubridate::year('04.24.2015')`?

Fr example: my date is **24th of April 2015**, written as `'24.04.2015'`.

I have tried:

```
`anydate('24.04.2015')` # leads to `NA`

 `as.Date('24.04.2015')` # leads to Error: 
`Error in charToDate(x) : 
 character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

`as.Date('24-04-2015')`  # replacing dots by - leads to improper date
`[1] "0024-04-20"`
```

For correct reading, I need to manually shift MM and DD into US format: MM-DD-YYY

```
 > anydate('04.24.2015')  # if I change MMDD manually (from 24.04.2015 -> 04.24.2015), it works well. But how to make this automatically?
 [1] "2015-04-24"
```

How to easily convert EU date format `24.04.2015` into US one `04.24.2015`? Thank you!

Comment: Try with e.g. `lubridate::dmy("24.04.2015")` or `as.Date('24.04.2015', format = "%d.%m.%Y")` to convert to proper dates first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some base function:

```
# as.Date convert string to date, format put them in the format you want
format(as.Date('24.04.2015', format = '%d.%m.%Y'),'%m.%d.%Y')
"04.24.2015"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(text_date <- '04.24.2015')
(date_date <- as.Date(text_date,format="%m.%d.%Y"))

#now we have a date date, we can use lubridate to pull out the year month day numbers if we want
library(lubridate)

(year_part <- year(date_date))
(month_part <- month(date_date))
```